# Camel AggregatonStrategy wrong result

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using CAMEL to aggregate responses from two sources, one being xml and other json. Initially I have stubbed those responses and I am getting them from the file.
The goal is to aggregate the responses from both sources.

My aggregator route looks like this

```
    from("direct:fetchProfile")
    .multicast(new ProfileAggregationStrategy()).stopOnException()
    .enrich("direct:xmlProfile")
    .enrich("direct:jsonProfile")
    .end();
```

My "direct:xmlProfile" route looks like -

```
    from("direct:xmlProfile")
    .process(new Processor(){

    @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            String filename = "target/classes/xml/customerDetails.xml";
             InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            exchange.getIn().setBody(fileStream);
         }
     })
    .split(body().tokenizeXML("attributes", null))
    .unmarshal(jaxbDataFormat)
    .process(new Processor(){
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Profile legacyProfile = exchange.getIn().getBody(Profile.class);
            // some more processing here
            exchange.getIn().setBody(legacyProfile);
        }

    });
```

In the above route I am reading the xml from a file and then using jaxb converter to map elements of interest into the class denoted by 'Profile'. After calling this route, CAMEL calls ProfileAggregationStrategy. The code for this is -

```
    public class ProfileAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy{
       @Override
       public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
             // this is the problematic line
             Profile newProfile = newExchange.getIn().getBody(Profile.class);
             if (oldExchange == null){
                 return newExchange;
             } else {
                 Profile oldProfile = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(Profile.class);
                 // code to copy merge oldProfile with newProfile
                 return oldExchange;
             }

        }
    }
```

The issue is with the line marked as 'problematic line'. Even though in the final phase of the route 'direct:xmlProfile' I have explicitly put an object into the Body of the exchange, the newExchange in ProfileAggregationStrategy still shows that Body is of type iostream.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation about the splitter eip.

- http://camel.apache.org/splitter

As the *output* of the splitter is the input, unless you specify an aggregation strategy to the splitter where you can decide what the *output* should be. For example if you want to use the last splitted element, then there is a `UseLastestAggregrationStrategy` you can use.